# Error 'require' is not defined while trying to fetch my local json file in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm new to vuejs...
I tried to fetch my JSON data stored in a local JSON file, but the logic is to decide which JSON file's data to be fetched is dynamic.

I'm constantly receiving an error of `'require' is not defined` and I'm not sure how to fix it.
I checked a few solutions mentioning the integration of `webpack` or `browserify`, but I'm not sure that why is it required to integrate any one of this!

```
<script>

var mylib = require(`../components/${this.$route.params.uuid}.json`)

export default {
    name: "BloePage",
    data() {
        return {
            blogcontent: mylib
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I also tried the following way to directly access my JSON file, rather than keeping it dynamic. Still, I'm receiving the same here...

```
export default {
    name: "BloePage",
    data() {
        return {
            blogcontent: require('../components/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json')
        }
    }
}
```

Error -

```
16:26  error  'require' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./router/index.js 28:11-30:28
 @ ./main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.43.171:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./main.js
```

Comment: Are you using Vue.js directly in the browser(via a <script> tag) or bundling the source code via a CLI?

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd Thanks for asking. I'm not sure about bundling the source code via a CLI, so probably I would have been using vue.js directly in browser.

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd in package.json there is "build": "vue-cli-service build" option added in scripts. So I think its gonna be bundling the code via CLI.

Comment: but you know that `require` doesn't work in browsers, right? you need this lib: https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Comment: @FlashThunder I tried using `require` inside <template> tag, which worked fine. I thought will work within script too. Let me try to install requirejs.

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't refer to the Vue instance when you use it outside `export default`.

You'd have to parse it from the URL with `window.location`, or use a query param instead:

`http://your-url?uuid=1`

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const uuid = params.get('uuid');
console.log(uuid); // Output: 1
```

Comment: I tried using require directly inside export default, in place of mylib. But it didn’t worked. Occurring the same error as before. Thanks for sharing knowledge...

Comment: `require` wouldn't work inside `export default`, what I'm saying is `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does outside it

Comment: So, `this.$route.params.uuid` is `undefined`

Comment: Why `require` would be `undefined` depends on your setup. Could you post any code relevant to that?

Comment: Hi @Daniel_Knights I tried to import my json file within <script> tag. which is working fine. import jsonData from '../content_files/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json' but when I'm trying to use require('../content_files/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json') to access the same file, its not working and receiving same here....

Comment: Do I need to do any setup to use require? I used require before in <template> tag, which worked fine.

Comment: You shouldn't need to if you set up your project the standard way, i.e. `vue create project`

Comment: Yes. I've created my project using `vue create project-name` with default setup

Comment: I've updated my question. I think there is something wrong with require method I'm trying.... If is there any other way to get data instead of require. that will also be helpful.

Comment: Try `import myLib from '../components/UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW.json'`

Comment: Hi Daniel, that works fine. but again chaging that code to dynamic is not working. at the end what I need is  `params uuid` in place of `UUDD_WWAA_EEFF_EWWW_AAWW`